# Httplistener asynchronous handling with Powershell (New-ScriptBlockCallback) - still blocking

Tags: c#, powershell

The code below should handle requests asynchronously, however when calling /timeout (that gives 10sec timeout) the httplistener hangs also for all other requests that are made at the same time. Maybe someone can help me with the code to understand why asynchronous handling is not working?

With C# I have managed to get this work, however my understanding working with New-ScriptBlockCallback seems to be limited and I would like really much to get this work with PowerShell.

```
function New-ScriptBlockCallback 
    {
        [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingFunctions', '')]
        param(
            [parameter(Mandatory)]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [scriptblock]$Callback
        )

        # Is this type already defined?
        if (-not ( 'CallbackEventBridge' -as [type])) {
            Add-Type @' 
                using System; 

                public sealed class CallbackEventBridge { 
                    public event AsyncCallback CallbackComplete = delegate { }; 

                    private CallbackEventBridge() {} 

                    private void CallbackInternal(IAsyncResult result) { 
                        CallbackComplete(result); 
                    } 

                    public AsyncCallback Callback { 
                        get { return new AsyncCallback(CallbackInternal); } 
                    } 

                    public static CallbackEventBridge Create() { 
                        return new CallbackEventBridge(); 
                    } 
                } 
'@
        }
        $bridge = [callbackeventbridge]::create()
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $bridge -EventName callbackcomplete -Action $Callback -MessageData $args > $null
        $bridge.Callback
    }



$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add('http://+:8080/') 
$listener.Start()
Write-host 'Listening'

$StartServiceTime = Get-Date

$requestListener = {
            [cmdletbinding()]
            param($result)

            [System.Net.HttpListener]$listener = $result.AsyncState;

            $context = $listener.EndGetContext($result);
            $request = $context.Request
            $response = $context.Response

            if ($request.Url -match '/timeout$') 
                {
                    $timeout = 10
                    sleep $timeout
                    $message = "Timeout $timeout"
                    $response.ContentType = 'text/html'
                }
            else 
                {
                    #fast response without timeout
                    $message = "no timeout";
                    $response.ContentType = 'text/html' ;
                }

            [byte[]]$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($message)
            $response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.length
            $output = $response.OutputStream
            $output.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
            $output.Close()

    }  


$context = $listener.BeginGetContext((New-ScriptBlockCallback -Callback $requestListener), $listener)


while ($listener.IsListening)
    {

        If ($context.IsCompleted -eq $true) {$context = $listener.BeginGetContext((New-ScriptBlockCallback -Callback $requestListener), $listener)}


    }


$listener.Close()
Write-host 'Terminating ...'
```

The code above can be pasted directly to powershell console and it will run httplistener running on port 8080.

To test requests without timeout open new console and type (continuous loop):

```
for ($$) {Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:8080/}
```

To test the timeout open new console and type:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:8080/timeout
```

You will see that continuous requests will hang.